# Google Sheets - Convert comma to "#" before generate .CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script in a Google Sheet:

```
/** 
 * Create CSV file of Sheet2
 * Modified script written by Tanaike
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike
 * 
 * Additional Script by AdamD.PE
 * version 13.11.2022.1
 * https://support.google.com/docs/thread/188230855
 */

/** Date extraction added by Tyrone */
const date = new Date();

/** Extract today's date */
let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
let year = date.getFullYear();


if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
}

if (month < 10) {
    month = `0${month}`;
}

/** Show today's date */
let currentDate = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
/** Date extraction added by Tyrone */

function sheetToCsvModelo0101() {
  var filename = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() + "-01" + " - " + currentDate; // CSV file name
  filename = filename + '.csv';
  var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents();
  var folder;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    if (!(folder.getOwner().getEmail() == user || folder.getEditors().some(e => e.getEmail() == user))) {
      throw new Error("This user has no write permission for the folder.");
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("This user has no write permission for the folder.");
  }
  var SelectedRange = "A2:AB3";
  var csv = "";
  var v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(SelectedRange).getValues();
  v.forEach(function (e) {
    csv += e.join(",") + "\n";
  });
  var newDoc = folder.createFile(filename, csv, MimeType.CSV);
  console.log(newDoc.getId()); // You can see the file ID.
}
```

This script basically creates a `.CSV` file in the same folder where the worksheet is, using the range defined in `var SelectedRange`.

This script is applied to a button on the worksheet.

The question is: how do I make every comma typed in this spreadsheet be converted into another sign, like `#` before generating the `.CSV` file in the folder?

I would also like to know if instead of generating 1 file in the folder it is possible to generate 2 files, each with a name.

Comment: I found a script that converts a comma to another sign, but I'm having trouble integrating it with the existing function. The script is this one: [link](https://gist.github.com/jesusalber1/c995ff11bcf7cff6afbce385ade60441)

Comment: I would use textFinder

Comment: So, the thing is, I would like the script to execute this, so before the `.csv` file is generated by the script, the script would automatically replace any `","` in the text with `"#"` and then generate the `.csv` file with the commas .

Comment: Yeah textFinder is an object in google sheets.  So yeah I understood that you wanted to do it in the spreadsheet

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to scripting. I'm going to study about TextFinder, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The code in the link is using textfinder but you will have to edit it for the character you will to replace.

Comment: Yes, it works with TextFinder, but I couldn't get it to work in a way that replaces only in the exported .CSV, keeping the sheet intact. Any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that when the script is triggered using TextFinder it replaces the commas in the spreadsheet itself, and I want the replacement to happen only in the exported `.csv` file, the spreadsheet has to keep the commas.

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid a conflict between the comma and the column delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

> The question is: how do I make every comma typed in this spreadsheet be converted into another sign, like `#` before generating the `.CSV` file in the folder?

After you get the sheet values via [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), replace all instances of `,` in the resulting 2D array with `#`, using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

I think this is a better approach than [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) since sheet values are not modified.

#### Code snippet:

From your original sample, just add the following line:

```
// ...stuff...
var v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(SelectedRange).getValues();
v = v.map(r => r.map(c => c.replaceAll(",", "#"))); // Add this line
v.forEach(function (e) {
  csv += e.join(",") + "\n";
});
// ...stuff...
```

Comment: Excellent solution!! It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and patience in explaining the solution, this solves a big headache I was having. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to avoid conflicts between the comma in the cells and the csv delimiter then try doing the csv like this:

```
function sheetToCsv() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const params = { "method": "GET", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?gid=" + sh.getSheetId() + "&format=csv";
  const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  const csv = r.getContentText();
  return csv;
}
```

And then put it back in a spreadsheet like this:

```
function csvToSheet(csv) {
  const vs = Utilities.parseCsv(csv,',');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I'm doing this to avoid conflicts between the comma delimiter and texts that contain a comma.

I'm going to open the `.csv` in another software that interprets the lines and columns, but if the text has commas it ends up breaking the text.

Comment: If you create the csv with the first function and load it back with the second the you can leave them in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've found a solution that almost works the way I'd like.

I created 2 functions, one to convert `,` to `#` and another to convert `#` to `,` again, then after the `.csv` file creation is complete the script switches back from `#` to `,` .

```
/** 
 * Create CSV file of Sheet2
 * Modified script written by Tanaike
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike
 * 
 * Additional Script by AdamD.PE
 * version 13.11.2022.1
 * https://support.google.com/docs/thread/188230855
 */

var SelectedRange = "A2:AB3";
function searchAndReplace_ToHash() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(SelectedRange).createTextFinder(',').replaceAllWith('#');
}

function searchAndReplace_ToComma() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(SelectedRange).createTextFinder('#').replaceAllWith(',');
}

function sheetToCsv_02() {
  var filename = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetName() + "-01" + " - " + currentDate; // CSV file name
  filename = filename + '.csv';
  var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

searchAndReplace_ToHash()

  // I modified below script.
  var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents();
  var folder;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    if (!(folder.getOwner().getEmail() == user || folder.getEditors().some(e => e.getEmail() == user))) {
      throw new Error("This user has no write permission for the folder.");
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("This user has no write permission for the folder.");
  }
  var csv = "";
  var v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(SelectedRange).getValues();
  v.forEach(function (e) {
    csv += e.join(",") + "\n";
  });
  var newDoc = folder.createFile(filename, csv, MimeType.CSV);
  console.log(newDoc.getId()); // You can see the file ID.
  searchAndReplace_ToComma()
}
```

It solves the problem, but it would be perfect if this change was not visible in the spreadsheet.

Is it possible to make this substitution without displaying it in the spreadsheet?

As for your script suggestion, I would like to change as little as possible in this script I'm using, it works exactly the way I need it to work, except for the fact that the commas of words conflict with the column divisions.

Anyway, thank you very much for all your attention and patience!